# Counting multiple ranged criteria - Header qualifier

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Requesting your help with following -

I am trying to count total number of i5s (Models) needed for month of Jul for each Team AA, BB and CC.

With the formula I should be able to get an answer as AA needs 13 i5s in Jul, BB needs 2 and CC needs 22.

Or

Total i5s needed in Jul are 37.

I have tried

=COUNTIFS(INDEX($D$2:$G$100,0,MATCH("Jul",$D$2:$L$2,0)),"i5")

but I am sure something is missing as the count of i5s for Jul month is coming to 0. I guess I need to add one more range / criteria so that this formula will count / sum the total of Jul month colum for each of the i5 mentioned in the models column.

This data exists for all months until Dec as shown in the picture attached here with.

Output of this formula is to be used to estimate inventory consumption agaist existing stocks for each month / each model type.

The data represented in attached picture is dynamic but the headers are constant / fixed since they are actual months. Only the numbers for each team will keep changing hence I am looking for a formula which will continue to count / sum the numbers for each month & each team for type of model and keep calculating the change against available stock.

Hope this information helps to formulate a formula?

This is actual excel sheet format in which the data will be made available

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SU. Are all the data in the rest of the months already available? If so, is this not a simple matter of subtracting the sum of Aug and Sep from the total for Q3?

Comment: Your question is not clear and as is, this question is likely to be closed. Please edit the question with more details. For examples: Are you trying to build a summary table like your image? where is the data that is to be summarized? My guess is that you could just use a pivot table.

Comment: Thanks @FlexYourData gns100 - I have edited the question to include additional information. I am basically trying to build a auto calculation to forecast consumption of existing stocks and drive procurement decision basis each month consumtion for each type of processor model. I hope it is clearer now?

Answer (score 0):

please try this:

=SUMIF($B$2:$B$4,"i5",INDEX($C$2:$J$4,0,MATCH(C$1,$C$1:$J$1,0)))

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much...I will certainly try this. I were also experimenting a bit and tried this - =SUMPRODUCT((Approved!$B$3:$B$174=$H2)*(Approved!$D$3:$D$174=$A2)*(Approved!$E$2:$K$2=B$1)*(Approved!$E$3:$K$174)) - I have expanded the formula on internal production excel sheet hence cell numbers are bit different.

Comment: Please feel free to post back any updates.